# PHP mail message adding 'n' to every line. CRLF/LF?

Tags: php, newline

Im getting very annoying messages from my site, when I am trying to remind password:

```
n 
Ktoś prawdopodobnie Ty, prosił‚ o nowe hasło:n 

n hasło: now1694n 

n n Jeżeli chcesz aktywować to hasło kliknij tutaj:n 

n Jeżeli to nie ty prosiłeś o wygenerowanie nowego hasła, zignoruj tego e-mail'a.n 

n Pozdrawiamy serdecznien 
n sklep
nn 
n n 
Ten e-mail został wygenerowany automatycznie. Prosimy na niego nie odpowiadaćn 
n n
n
nn nn
```

How can I repair this?

Regards,
Rafa

Old topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520740/phpmail-adding-n-to-every-new-line

Comment: sending new password with mail is highly insecure, you don't show any part of code, so we can't help you

Comment: Yea I know but as far I tried to show code, I don`t know which one. 
http://www.pastebin.pl/view/6d597072

http://www.pastebin.pl/view/926824a3

Answer (score 1):

Probably, there is a misspelling in your code. Try to use `\n` or `\r\n` instead of `n`. If you generate this string with javascript first, then with php or you have a similar situation, you should try to use `\\n` or `\\r\\n`.

Comment: I think emails are sended via:
"Software: PHPMailer - PHP email class,   Version: 2.2.1  "

In code of sendind script? In email template are used : <br />

Comment: You can use `br2nl()` [br2nl() function php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)